# Displaying a hidden text box when a particular option value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a hidden text-box visible when a particular option value is selected, It works when there are multiple options available obviously because it responds to onChange. How can I get it to work if that is the only option present, the first select box in my Example.

Js Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8bm9R/

This is my Js function

```
function showOther(fieldObj, otherFieldID) {
    var fieldValue = fieldObj.options[fieldObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var otherFieldObj = document.getElementById(otherFieldID);
    otherFieldObj.style.visibility = (fieldValue == 'other') ? '' : 'hidden';
    return;
}
```

Comment: Seems working to me [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bm9R/1/). Just selected _No wrap - in <head>_ from the left side.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working...

Comment: btw, just fyi, you dont have to do `fieldObj.options[fieldObj.selectedIndex].value` to get the value. Just `fieldObj.value` would do.

Comment: No wrap - in <head> ???

Comment: The second select box is working yes, How can I get the text box to appear if that is the only value in the dropdown(first dropdown in example), what kind of event will that be?

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the JsFiddle:

Basically   JsFiddle is misused, the function should be set to be wrapped in the header instead of 'onLoad'.

[jsfiddle.net/8bm9R/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/8bm9R/2/)

```
function showOther(fieldObj, otherFieldID)
{

    var fieldValue = fieldObj.options[fieldObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var otherFieldObj = document.getElementById(otherFieldID);

    otherFieldObj.style.visibility = (fieldValue=='other') ? '' : 'hidden';

    return;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: How to make the first select work, in which the only option is that which makes the text box appear. what event would that be. sorry i am new to js.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").change(function() {
if($(this).val() == "expected_value") {
otherFieldObj.style.visibility = "visible"
}
else {
otherFieldObj.style.visibility = "hidden"
}
});
```